# solrj:Always get 403 code when send request to Solr by using SOlrj

Tags: java, solr

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.http.ParseException: Invalid content type: 
    at org.apache.http.entity.ContentType.parse(ContentType.java:233)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.executeMethod(HttpSolrServer.java:496)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:210)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.HttpSolrServer.request(HttpSolrServer.java:206)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.AbstractUpdateRequest.process(AbstractUpdateRequest.java:124)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.deleteById(SolrServer.java:239)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrServer.deleteById(SolrServer.java:225)
    at com.bjsxt.FFFF.testDelete(FFFF.java:50)
    at com.bjsxt.FFFF.main(FFFF.java:27)
```

Now that I can access the `SOlr` well, I can submit the query without issues.

I'm using the same version of `Solr&SolrJ`. I installed the `SOlr` in my Win7.

Can anyone give me any suggestion on how to resolve the issue?

I check the `solr logs`, seems my java code will never send out the request to the server.I can't see the logs for my java code.

Comment: Your java code is not able to access the solr. Check the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

This indicates that, not able to connect to Solr. It expects a binary response, but instead gets a HTML page with HTTP code 403 Forbidden.

Comment: Yes.I set a breakpoint there and follow it, found that seems the server does not respond to it.  Now that I found that I can pass the test with a new server----the one that native with the solr----I mean, just download the solr and go to the bin folder to start the server, when i use the same code to access this server, it works. So I think maybe there is a issue with the solr server that I created(I used to copy the .war out and put some libs to the folder to run) Thank for your reply!

Comment: I don't want to waste too much time on how to creating the solr server....